# Possible to make a singleton struct in C++? How?

Tags: c++, struct, singleton

I like to experiment around as I learn more about coding. I have a program that would only require a single instance of a struct for the life of it's runtime and was wondering if it's possible to create a singleton struct. I see lot's of information on making a singleton class on the internet but nothing on making a singleton struct. Can this be done? If so, how?

Thanks in advance. Oh, and I work in C++ btw.

Comment: Remember that in C++ a `class` and `struct` are the same. The only difference is that a `struct` defaults to members being `public`.

Comment: Does that mean you can put methods in a struct? (if they are the 'same'). And, if so, then I can do things like operator overloading in a struct?

Comment: Note that static initialisation is not thread safe before C++11 so you would need a mutex to prevent a race condition if you call the ``singleton::get_instance()`` from multiple threads.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and inheritance defaults to `public` too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Struct and class are in C++ almost the same (the only difference is default visibility of members).

Note, that if you want to make a singleton, you have to prevent struct/class users from instantiating, so hiding ctor and copy-ctor is inevitable.

```
struct Singleton
{
private:
    static Singleton * instance;

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    Singleton(const Singleton & source)
    {
        // Disabling copy-ctor
    }

    Singleton(Singleton && source)
    {
        // Disabling move-ctor
    }

public:
    static Singleton * GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == nullptr)
            instance = new Singleton();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could put methods in structs like that. Thanks. I'm upvoting this because a simple code example was one of the thngs I really wanted (not the only thing, but a very important thing).

Comment: Turns out this is Java, not C++. With a little tweaking it can be made to work thoug - just that it won't compile wtih g++ as it is shown.

Answer (score 10):

A `class` and a `struct` are pretty much the same thing, except for some minor details (such as default access level of their members). Thus, for example:

```
struct singleton
{
    static singleton& get_instance()
    {
        static singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    // The copy constructor is deleted, to prevent client code from creating new
    // instances of this class by copying the instance returned by get_instance()
    singleton(singleton const&) = delete;

    // The move constructor is deleted, to prevent client code from moving from
    // the object returned by get_instance(), which could result in other clients
    // retrieving a reference to an object with unspecified state.
    singleton(singleton&&) = delete;

private:

    // Default-constructor is private, to prevent client code from creating new
    // instances of this class. The only instance shall be retrieved through the
    // get_instance() function.
    singleton() { }

};

int main()
{
    singleton& s = singleton::get_instance();
}
```

Comment: @Spook: Correct. I forgot to add the `static` keyword. I did that in my mind only. Edited, thank you.

Comment: You did not hid the copy-ctor and = operator. One may create a instance by copying existing instance of singleton. Effectively you have to implement the singleton as you would do it if `singleton` was a class.

Comment: @Spook: Actually, I guess the assignment operator does not need to be protected, but the move constructor does. I will edit again

Comment: I have actually preferred to `delete` copy construction and assignment. I cannot see what use keeping private versions would have, but I haven't really thought it through very much.

Comment: Now you are getting too excited with the deletes :-D Aside from the syntax error here ``singleton() { } = delete;`` you need at least one ctor so that you can construct the object.

Comment: @RomanKutlak: Aand you are correct as well. Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, a `struct` and a `class` are the same in C++, so a making singleton `struct` is the same as making a singleton `class`.

The only difference between `class` and `struct` are the default access specifiers and base class inheritance: `private` for `class` and `public` for `struct`. For example,

```
class Foo : public Bar 
{ 
 public: 
  int a;
};
```

is the same as

```
struct Foo : Bar
{
 int a;
};
```

So, there is no fundamental difference when it comes to singletons. Just make sure to read about [why singletons are considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Here's a simple implementation:

```
struct singleton
{
  static singleton& instance()
  {
    static singleton instance_;
    return instance_;
  }
  singleton(const singleton&)=delete;            // no copy
  singleton& operator=(const singleton&)=delete; // no assignment

 private:
  singleton() { .... } // constructor(s)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `struct` and `class` only refer to the default access of members. You can do everything with a struct that you can do with a class. Now if you were referring to POD structs, things get more complicated. You can't defined a custom constructor, so there's no way to enforce only a single object creation. However, there's nothing stopping you from simply only instantiating it once.

Comment: Thank you. Very succinct and comprehansive. Reading this makes it all pretty clear to me.

Comment: Definition of POD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c

Comment: Now, wait a minute, does this mean I can't include attributes in my singleton struct design? That's kind of the whole point. The one instance of the struct in the program is only every used as a temporary transition place for data (a record with 4 fields). The following is the code I have for my struct but was hoping to 'add' code to it, to make it a singleton:
<code>
     struct Record { //the record - temporary - reuse - singleton?
         int DeptNum;
         char Name[MAXNAME];
         int Age;
         int EmplID;  // key field

     };
</code>

Answer (score 0):

`class` and `struct` is *almost* a synonyms in C++. For singleton use case they are complete synonyms.