# Why should I delete move constructor and move assignment operator in a singleton?

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, move-semantics

I have the following Singleton policy-class implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    Singleton(){}; // so we cannot accidentally delete it via pointers
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete; // no copies
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete; // no self-assignments
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete; // WHY?
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete; // WHY?
public:
    static T& getInstance() // singleton
    {
        static T instance; // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
                       // Instantiated on first use.
                       // Thread safe in C++11
        return instance;
    }
};
```

which I then use via the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)

```
class Foo: public Singleton<Foo> // now Foo is a Singleton
{
    friend class Singleton<Foo>;
    ~Foo(){}
    Foo(){};
public:
// rest of the code
};
```

I cannot figure out why I should delete the move constructor and assignment operator. Can you give me a single example where I end up breaking the singleton if I don't delete (don't define at all) the move ctor and assignment operator?

Comment: Where did you read that you should?

Comment: No reason, you don't have to do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187331/3093378 and I remember seeing it in some other code examples, although I cannot recall. I wondered why, because I thought that if I delete the copy ctor, then no move ctor will be defined implicitly

Comment: What's your use case for assignment/moving actually, otherwise of asking for a language definition for this case?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried to see if I really need to declare it as deleted (i.e., if not, was it possible to break the singleton pattern by somehow moving e.g. in a vector the object returned by the `getInstance()`, i.e. invalidating the instance.)

Comment: @vsoftco And what's your use case saying that you need a singleton at all BTW? Are you asking for an XY problem?

Comment: @vsoftco: Yeah, you thought right. Those examples are silly.

Comment: May be all of [**these Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+singleton+user%3A1413395) are actually related ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I really need a singleton. I am implementing a library in which I need to have a whole set of predefined templated `Eigen` matrices, before the `main()`. There is no way of initializing them in the header, so I need a global class in which the initialization is done in the constructor. These are global resources for my library.

Comment: @vsoftco _'I really need a singleton'_ That's certainly OK, if you are sure. I've often used singletons, though really tried to have them **once** per system. The next step is to define what _system_ is, and why it needs a single unique instance of something (kind of _'main applicatoin'_ may be).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you declare a copy constructor (even if you define it as `delete`d in the declaration), no move constructor will be declared implicitly. Cf. C++11 12.8/9:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>
> — ...

Since you do have a user-declared copy constructor, there won't be a move constructor at all if you don't declare one. So you can just get rid of the move constructor declaration-definition entirely. Same for the move-assignment operator.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out the standard! That's what I thought, I was never able to "trick" the compiler into moving my object.

Comment: @vsoftco: Sometimes the easiest way to understand how things work is to read the rules... they may be a little daunting, but I highly recommend it :-)

Comment: Yes, I tried, but don't have standard and didn't find the exact rule about when the move ctor is not declared implicitly. For example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor I didn't realize that when you `delete` a copy ctor you are actually "declare" it :)

Comment: @vsoftco: Yes, yes, you have to pay careful attention to the language. User-provided, user-declared, user-defined, implicitly-defined, implicitly-declared... you can get the current working draft paper of the standard [from GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft).

Comment: Ohh I didn't know, thank a lot for the link, I didn't want to pay for it :)

Comment: @vsoftco: Right. As they say, "You can't own the standard." (because nobody can afford it). But you can own countless copies of the working draft, in all its stages. Some stages are tagged as "releases", e.g. the one after publication of C++11...

Comment: +1 My opinion is in agreement with your answer but even stronger:  As a style guide, I recommend that the move members **never** be deleted.  At best their deletion is redundant.  At worst, their deletion is a bug (not in this case though).  So in code reviews, if I see deleted move members, that forces me to check to make sure we are not in bug territory.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, what do you mean exactly by "deleted move members"?

Comment: @Vassilis:  I use the term "move members" to refer to the move constructor and move assignment operator.  If they are "deleted", that means that they are  defined using `= delete`.  Here is more in-depth rationale for my position on this matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820178/576911